# SQLite How to use LIKE on a column and add wild cards

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

I'm trying to compare 2 similar columns from 2 tables in SQLite. I wrote this which doesn't throw an error but also doesn't return anything and I know it should.

```
SELECT t1.* from t1, t2 Where t1.col1 Like '%'||t2.col1||'%';
```

I'm looking for when `t2.col1` is embedded inside of `t1.col1`. Both columns are of type TEXT.

Note: I'm using the C-Interface in C++ with Visual Studio 2010.

Ideas?

Edit:

I've played around with pulling a value out of `t2.col1` that matches something in `t1.col1` and writing something like this,

```
SELECT t1.* from t1, t2 Where t1.col1 Like '%ValueInT1%';
```

which works and returns something.

Is there a bug with SQLite when concatenating the '%' character in a `like` statement or is there a different syntax I should be using? I'm at a loss for why this isn't working.

I've also seen an SQL function called `Locate` which people use in different Databases to do this kind of check. Does SQLite have a Locate function?

EDIT 2:

I've run the first SQL statement in SQLite Administrator with some of my data and it DOES find it. Could there be a simpler problem? There are '_' in the data could that be causing a problem with the like?

Comment: Have you run the query in SQLite Administrator or a similar tool? are t1.col1 and t2.col1 of the same string type?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm also not familiar with that tool how does it work? And yes both columns are of type TEXT. Ill update the question.

Comment: You can add functions relatively easily to SQLite; it's a supported extension point (though they do defeat the query optimizer)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(V.V) The answer was that I was joining to the wrong column in the real table. 2 columns had very similar names and I was checking the wrong one.

Thanks for the help.